# Track views of rss feeds in newsreaders?

Tags: rss, google-analytics

Is there a way to track if a blog post has been viewed but not clicked on in a newsreader? For example, when I read through my rss feeds in Google Reader, I generally read the entire article in Google Reader so I never click on the link to the article and therefore it is not tracked in Google Analytics. We use feedburner to track rss clicks.

Comment: Do you want to track your RSS feed reads using Google Analytics specifically? Or would any tracking solution do?

Comment: Is there a good image-based (free) package we can use to track impressions on RSS feeds?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible, unfortunately, because you can't embed the JavaScript needed to trigger the pageview into a newsfeed.

Answer (score 2):

You would need a service to make the correct requests to the Google Analytics API or redirect to it. There are two APIs you can use:

- the __utm.gif "API"
- the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) API

To use the later (you need Universal Analytics), which is way better in my opinion, you would need to make a request or redirect to something like:

`http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?z=<randomnumber>&t=pageview&dh=<domainname>&cid=<unique-client-uuid>&tid=<propertyid>&v=1dp=<path>`

Where:

- `<randomnumber>` is a random number to avoid caches (especially if you do redirects)
- `<domainname>` is the domain name you see in your tracking code
- `<propertyid>` is the property id you see in your tracking code (eg: UA-123456)
- `<path>` is the path to the page you want to register the pageview for. Note that it must be quoted. Eg, for `/path/to/page` you would need to send `%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fpage`

I've implemented a simple redirector service that does exactly that [here](https://github.com/ionelmc/t.ionelmc.ro) (explained at length [here](http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2013/11/01/pelican-feed-analytics/))

If you're stuck with the Classic Analytics then you would need to use [nojsstats](http://nojsstats.blogspot.com/) or [the older implementation](https://github.com/ionelmc/t.ionelmc.ro/blob/d92c778a59a47984306a92e12136b9e439c9f707/views.py)